# Is there any sequence that is in the range of $[0,1]$ that converges to something outside of this range?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any sequence that is in the range of $\cdots\cup[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup\cdots$  that converges to something outside of this range?  I thought about taking a sequence such as $ \{\frac{n}{n+1}\}$ but this clearly converges to $1$. In any case I haven't been able to find a sequence that converges outside of this range

Comment: What definition of "*closed sets*" are you using?  Is the set you describe closed?

Comment: So the def my text gives goes as follows: A subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is called closed if for every convergent sequence $\{a_k\}_k \subset A$ the limit $\lim_{i \to \infty}a_k$ lies in A.

Comment: Good.  Now... is the set you describe closed?  It is the union of intervals of the form $[a,b]$ which you should know from example are all closed as well... The union of closed sets is also closed.  And as per the definition of closed you are using... every sequence of elements from your set which converge must converge to something *inside* the range, never outside.

Comment: The union of closed sets is not always closed. But wouldn't it not be closed since we have points such as -1.5 in the set?

Comment: Fair, I misspoke.  This set though will be.  A way of seeing it then, look at the complement of the set, $\dots \cup(-1,0)\cup(1,2)\cup (3,4)\cup \dots$ which you should see as open.  As for $-1.5$, irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n$ tend to a limit $x$. Then, for sufficiently large $n$, $|x_n-x|<0.5$.

Then all these $x_n$ are in **one** of the sets $[2n,2n+1]$, which is a closed set. Therefore $x$ is also in this set.